# Restore navigation stack when Xamarin.Forms app resumes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, state-management

I'm building an app that has these pages, in order:

`(P)`: `ContentPage`
`(V)`: `ContentView` hosted on a `ContentPage`.
`->`: Call or code being executed.

```
(P) Main
   -> If login not detected, automatically goes to:
       (P) Startup
           (P) Sign up, has these ContentViews as registration steps:
               (V) Email and password
               (V) Name
               (V) Profile photo
                   -> Call to CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync
               (V) Other details
                   -> Returns to Main, if has successful profile creation.
           (P) Sign in
               -> Returns to Main, if has successful login.
   -> If login detected:
        -> Load the content of the Main page.
```

So, whenever I lock the screen of my app or switch apps (such as opening the camera, by calling the CrossMedia plugin), the app goes directly to the Main page again, which directs the user back to the Startup page, in case there's no login detected.

Is there any way to solve this issue? How?
Should I save the navigation stack somewhere on the OnSleep method?
What about the DataContext of each page? How can I save them?

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a App level property when your app going to sleep mode or your contentPage disappearing. If it is true you can skip your login check in resume method and let user resume the app where it left.

In App.xaml.cs

```
public static bool IsSignUpInProgress{get;set;}

protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            if(Application.Current.MainPage==typeof(SignUpPage))
                IsSignUpInProgress=true;
        }
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        if(IsSignUpInProgress==false)
            {
                //Do your login check.
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to detect the issue by adding breakpoints on the MainPage startup methods.

Basically what I had to do was to check if the page was already loaded or not, by using a simple bool variable (`_loaded`).

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        IsBusy = true;

        if (!_loaded && !await ViewModel.Auth.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            _loaded = true;
            await App.NavigationHelper.NavigateModalAsync(new Startup(), false);
        }

        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

When the app resumes, even when switching apps, like the camera, the `MainPage` was executing the `OnAppearing` method.

There's no other call to this page other than the one at the `App.xaml.cs` constructor, so the framework must be calling it because it's the main page of the app.